# My for loop seems to be executing too many times. Help please! Thank you

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I'm hoping someone can help me. I am checking if a set of coordinates I have are within a range of coordinates from a hurricane track. My dataset is quite large (over 10k) so I have just taken a small sample to show my code.
When I run my for loop and if statement, the loop seems to iterating more times than it should (it seems to not move onto the next iterable).
In the code the list of lists *ida* is my hurricane track coordinates and *sample* is my locations coordinates with an ID column.

```
ida = [['IDA', 18.6, -80.5],
 ['IDA', 18.619048, -80.571429],
 ['IDA', 18.638095, -80.642857],
 ['IDA', 18.657143, -80.714286],
 ['IDA', 18.67619, -80.785714],
 ['IDA', 18.695238, -80.857143],
 ['IDA', 18.714286, -80.928571],
 ['IDA', 18.733333, -81.0],
 ['IDA', 18.752381, -81.071429],
 ['IDA', 18.771429, -81.142857]]

sample = [[25820, 25.891041, -80.383553],
 [25821, 34.016776, -117.837528], [25822, 33.812013, -117.886268],
 [25823, 47.980291, -122.207616], [25824, 32.553882, -116.978896],
 [25825, 34.102001, -118.324049], [25826, 33.410692, -112.418414], 
[25827, 51.503139, 5.477582], [25828, 52.248382, -0.810513], 
[99999, 18.6, -80.5][99998,18.6,-80.5]]
```

Note: Last 2 lists in sample are self inputted to check that the loop is working (its the same point as a storm coordinate).

cargo[0][1] == the ID.

The loop:

````
ID_exposed = []
for loc in sample:
    for H in ida:
        if ((loc[1] > H[1]-0.6) and (loc[1] < H[1]+0.6)) and (loc[2] > H[2]-0.7) and (loc[2] < H[2]+0.7):
            ID_exposed.append(loc)```
print(ID_exposed)
````

Output:

```
[[99999, 18.6, -80.5], [99999, 18.6, -80.5], [99999, 18.6, -80.5], [99999, 18.6, -80.5], [99999, 18.6, -80.5], [99999, 18.6, -80.5], [99999, 18.6, -80.5], [99999, 18.6, -80.5], [99999, 18.6, -80.5], [99999, 18.6, -80.5]]
```

Edit: My desired output is that I get a list of the locations from sample that satisfy my if statement (are in the range of my `ida` coordinates).
E.g.

```
ID_exposed = [[99999, 18.6, -80.5],[99998, 18.6, -80.5]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: add a break line after your condition is met and loc is appended to ID_exposed. This won't solve your code from running too many times, but it will help stop the duplicate points from being added to your ID_exposed list.

Hello,

When I ran your code, it looks like it was appending the same data point over and over again. In the sample you gave, there is one ID that is meeting your condition. However, it is doing that exact comparison 10 times and appending it each time.

Therefore, I recommend adding a break each time your condition is met and the data was appended. This reduced the number of loops from 100 to 90, and the length of ID_exposed reduced from 10 to 1.

It looks like that for each sample point you are also iterating through the ida data. So the number of times it should loop would be equal to len(ida) * len (sample).In this example, both ida and sample have length 10, so it should loop 10 x 10 or 100 times. I ran this with a counter for each time it looped through the function and at the end the counter was 100, which would signal that the code is running the correct number of times.

Below is the sample that I used to validate it was running the correct number of times.

```
ID_exposed = []
ct = 0
for loc in sample:
    for H in ida:
        if ((loc[1] > H[1]-0.6) and (loc[1] < H[1]+0.6)) and (loc[2] > H[2]-0.7) and (loc[2] < H[2]+0.7):
            ID_exposed.append(loc)
        ct += 1
print(ID_exposed)
print(ct)
```

This is the changed I made to make it run 90 times instead of 100

```
ID_exposed = []
ct = 0
for loc in sample:
    for H in ida:
        if ((loc[1] > H[1]-0.6) and (loc[1] < H[1]+0.6)) and (loc[2] > H[2]-0.7) and (loc[2] < H[2]+0.7):
            ID_exposed.append(loc)
            break
        ct += 1
print(ID_exposed)
print(ct)
```

Comment: Thanks joeysprite, the break fixed the problem. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

So I'm a bit confused as to what you're expected output it. What your code is doing right now, is iterating through your `sample` list, and for each iteration in `sample` it iterates through every item in `ida`. If a certain number of criteria pass, it adds that iteration of `sample` to your `ID_exposed` list. It continues doing this until you've run through every item in the `sample` list.

If you want it to stop after adding a certain number of locations to the list, you should add a counter and an If Statement with a `break` or `continue` statement in it:

```
ID_exposed.append(loc)
counter += 1
if counter > 5:    #make it whatever number you want
    break          #the loop with break, and you will now exit your for loop
```

If you're looking for something else, you'll need to update your question to give us a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am looking to get a list of locations from the `sample` data that are in the range (Lat +-o.6, Long +-0.7). So I want to get the set of coordinates from sample, loop through the set of coordinates in ida and check against each one if the sample coordinates are within range. If so, append that set of coordinates to ID_exposed, then move onto the next set of coordinates from `sample`.
I hope this has clarified.